# Динамическая генерация xml по xsd Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Необходимо в java коде динамически гинерировать xml по xsd схеме, в которой есть элементы с разными паттернами. Например:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AnyType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]|[A-F]{48}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Я использовал [XMLBeans Tools](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/guide/tools.html) и [Java-based XSD to XML generator](https://github.com/mkris/xsd2xml), но эти инструменты не заполняют нужный элемент по паттерну. Существуют ли библиотеки, реализующие возможность генерации xml по xsd схеме с соблюдением паттернов?

Comment: Поясните, для чего вы это хотите? Какую задачу решаете?

Comment: Нужно будет гинерить xml, преобразовывать ее с помощью DOM, потом валидировать с другой xsd.  Конечно можно с помощью JAXB решить задачу. Но xsd схемы будут разные и их будет много. В тестах нужно заполнять объекты dto потом маршалить в xml. Хотелось бы гинерить xml сразу с заполненными всеми валидными элементами.

Comment: из чего вы генерирует xml? данные в источнике соответствую желаемому формату?

Comment: генерирую xml из схемы xsd. Второй вопрос не понятен. Какой источник?

Comment: схема описывает формат данных. а откуда данные берутся?

Comment: мне и нужно чтобы атрибуты или значения элементов заполнялись любыми валидными значениями, учитывая паттерны

Comment: Поясните, для чего вы это хотите? Какую задачу решаете?

Comment: В основном для следующего: Происходит вызов удаленных методов через RMI. Это дело нужно тестить. В тестах осуществляется валидация того что отправилось. Чтобы не создавать разнообразные и большие(в плане заполнения полей) объекты вручную, а потом маршалить их в xml, было бы удобнее сразу генерировать передаваемую xml со всеми заполненными полями корневого тэга.

Comment: то есть вы хотите что-то тестировать?

Comment: Это не имеет значения

Comment: это имеет значение. так как тестирование это совершенно отдельная тема. то что вы хотите называется property testing.